# Get "ParseError" with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

Most time scraper works normally, but sometimes I get

```
2014-08-28 11:02:27-0700 [aqicn] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://site_address_com/> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.web._newclient.ParseError'>>]
```

I cannot understand why it happening. Who have same problem? May be it twisted bug? I try find something, but I got only  partial official documentation.

Comment: What is the request time delay you put in the setting? Try to slow down your robots and see if the error still exist. It happened to me before and it seems like is server cannot catch up and time out in the end.

Comment: You talking about this parameter? DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1

Comment: Yes, that was what I mean. I think that is a decent download_delay for most sites... maybe you can try to change it to 5 and see if the error still exist?

Comment: Yes, it same, error isn't disappeared. I thinking, may be sever make some blocking for request. Because at first this errors weren't recently, but now it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As were thinking @nramirezuy and @B.Mr.W scraper was banned on site. I use TOR and now I don't get this error. Thank you guys for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running into [this bug](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/345). As you can see there is no official fix right now, just a monkey patch on the ticket.

Comment: I have " <class 'twisted.web._newclient.ParseError'>" but in bug page "<class 'scrapy.xlib.tx._newclient.ParseError'>". I think this is different.

Comment: @Infernion Is the same error, you are probably using another version of scrapy; all in `scrapy.xlib.tx` is twisted extended stuff. Can you reproduce this with the site? (I'm assuming you have curl) https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/345#issuecomment-41310605

Comment: Can you say where put _monkey_patching_HTTPClientParser_statusReceived() because I not really understand

Comment: Oh this monkey patch not for my problem. @Tonal has ERROR and brake scrape. But my ERROR appears and doesn't prevents for work of Scrapy.

Comment: I think you are getting banned by the site, and on those ban responses the site is sending malformed headers triggering this error.